# Error: No AWSAccessKey was presented - flutter Amplify

Tags: flutter, http-status-code-404

I have a code like this in my flutter project:

```dart
final imageUrl = await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: urlKey);

return StreamBuilder(
stream: imageUrl.url,
builder: (context, snapshot) {

if (snapshot.hasData) {

if (snapshot.data.length != 0) {
return GridView.builder(
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
crossAxisCount: 1),
itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: snapshot.data,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          });
    } else {
      // 5
      return Center(child: Text('No images to display.'));
    }
  } else {
    // 6
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Add a little more info, what do you want to achive

Comment: Actually, I wanted to list some pictures from my existing S3 bucket that I'd used for a webapp in my flutter app, but it was giving me 400 error from the console and awsaccesskey error on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that in order to access an existing object from your bucket with amplify, you have to put those objects in a Public folder. So your URL should be something like: aws..../public/other-folders-or-assets